# What is a good way to record time periods in Rails application, so that I can easily use them for calculations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have time periods like:

- 2 years
- 1 month
- 4 days

I would like to add them to existing records in my DB in a way that I could easily use them for calculations? The type of calculations I would need would be [time_period] - (Time.now - [datetime]) in order to see how much of the time period is left.

Since my periods are quite standard, I was thinking to save the time periods as strings "2-years", "1-month", "4-days" etc. and split them on use. For example "4-days" could become something like this:

```
4.send("days".to_sym)
```

What do you think about this method? Any better ideas?

Comment: Where do you need to do these calculations, inside the database or only inside Ruby? Which databases do you care about?

Comment: The calculations will be only inside Ruby. I'm using MySQL. I would like to print the "time period" and use it for the calculations to get time left.

Comment: Then I think your proposed solution is reasonable but I'd split the time period into two columns (amount and units). BTW, you don't have to `to_sym` when using `send`, it is happy with strings too.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i have a better solution.

[Here is the Class TimeDuration](https://gist.github.com/addisaden/4cd682f5415059eac0ae)

```
five_minutes = TimeDuration.new("5 min")
five_minutes + Time.now

Time.now
# => 2013-09-13 02:50:06 +0200
five_minutes + Time.now
# => 2013-09-13 02:55:13 +0200
```

Comment: Be sure to calculate "five_minutes + Time.now", the other way "Time.now + five_minutes" doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to store them all in a standardized format; like seconds, so that you can easily do calculations without having to first convert things.  If you also stored some sort of units field (i.e. years, days, minutes, seconds), you could then easily convert the seconds back to their appropriate units for display - sort of like what you have above.

```
stored_value_in_minutes = stored_value.seconds / 1.minutes
```